# При нажатии не открываю блоки

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте! Написал две функции появления и исчезновения блоков, но они почему-то не открываются. При клике просто ничего не происходит. В чём проблема кода? Почему оно не открывает блоки?

HTML:

```
<div class="radio">
   <label><input onclick="hide(full)" id="full" type="radio" checked name="family" value="Полная"/>Полная<br/></label>
   <label><input onclick="show(notfull)" id="notfull" type="radio" name="family" value="Неполная"/>Неполная<br/></label>
</div>
<div class="field" id="second" style="display:none;">
   <div id="family">
      <label><input type="radio" name="how1" value="Студент без матери."/>Студент без матери.<br/></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="how1" value="Студент без отца."/>Студент без отца.<br/></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="how1" value="Мать-одиночка."/>Мать-одиночка.<br/></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="how1" value="Родители разведены."/>Родители разведены.<br/></label><br/>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var mest=document.getElementById('mest');
var inog=document.getElementById('inog');
var full=document.getElementById('full');
var notFull=document.getElementById('notfull');
var first=document.getElementById('first');
var second=document.getElementById('second');

function hide(a) {
   if(a==mest){
      first.style.display="none";
   }
   if(a==full){
      second.style.display="none";
   }
};
function show(a) {
   if(a==inog){
      first.style.display="block";
   }
   if(a==notfull){
      second.style.display="block";
   }
};
```

Comment: js код находится в отдельном файле и он подключен правильно

Comment: Поставь все значения переменных в кавычки (пример: из a==mest  в a=="mest")

Comment: И так же при вызове фунций ( пример: из hide(full) в hide("full") )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас переменные не взяты в кавычки.

Исправленный код:

HTML:

```
<div class="radio">
   <label><input onclick="hide('full')" id="full" type="radio" checked name="family" value="Полная"/>Полная<br/></label>
   <label><input onclick="show('notfull')" id="notfull" type="radio" name="family" value="Неполная"/>Неполная<br/></label>
</div>
<div class="field" id="second" style="display:none;">
   <div id="family">
      <label><input type="radio" name="how1" value="Студент без матери."/>Студент без матери.<br/></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="how1" value="Студент без отца."/>Студент без отца.<br/></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="how1" value="Мать-одиночка."/>Мать-одиночка.<br/></label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="how1" value="Родители разведены."/>Родители разведены.<br/></label><br/>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var mest=document.getElementById('mest');
var inog=document.getElementById('inog');
var full=document.getElementById('full');
var notFull=document.getElementById('notfull');
var first=document.getElementById('first');
var second=document.getElementById('second');

function hide(a) {
    if(a == 'mest'){
        first.style.display="none";
    }
    if(a == 'full'){
        second.style.display="none";
    }
};
function show(a) {
    if(a == 'inog'){
        first.style.display="block";
    }
    if(a == 'notfull'){
        second.style.display="block";
    }
};
```

Comment: @AsLan, не за что. Без кавычек могут указываться только цифры и стандартные переменные (true, false, undefined и т. п.)